# Excel 2013 VBA not running for specific user in specific file

Tags: vba, excel

We have a spreadsheet with some VBA in it that compiles data from multiple tabs to generate a score and pull over comments.

I am the only user who cannot run the macro.  When I try to run the macro, either via the macro button or directly from the macro window, nothing happens.  This issue is specific to this single file, as I'm working all the time with macro-enabled workbooks.  So the problem isn't tied to my Trust Center settings.

My only smoking gun is that most of the code sits in the "ThisWorkbook" Excel Object.  If I try to move some of the code to a module, then I can run it, although I get an error since the code was designed to sit in ThisWorkbook.

Any idea why I would be the only person who can't run this macro?  Also, I've disabled all add-ins, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Check if your macro workbook didn't end up in Excel's Disabled Items (File/Options/Add-Ins/Manage - select "Disabled Items" and press "Go" (that's the order in Excel 2016, so may be slightly different in 2013) If your workbook is there, enable it.

Comment: The only disabled item was Microsoft Excel Previewer.  I tried enabling and re-opening the file.  Still having the same issue.

Comment: It may not be that "nothing" is happening, but an error may be getting trapped and silently handled/ignored.   Open the VB editor and put a breakpoint at the start of the sub you're calling - does it hit that breakpoint?